# Питон задача тема контекстный менеджер

Tags: python

Написал такой код. Не могу понять как сделать так что бы при открытии несуществующего файла менеджер автоматически создавал и открывал этот файл в режиме записи?

```
class File():
  def __init__(self,filename,mode):
    self.filename=filename
    self.mode=mode
    self.file=None
      
  def __enter__(self):
    self.file=open(self.filename)
    return self.file
    
  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.file.close()

with File('example.txt','w') as file:
    file.write('Всем привет')
```

Answer (score 1):

Не написал, а скопировал.
Если бы ты писал, причем уже с уровнем классов, как в примере, то вопрос у тебя такой не возникал бы.
У тебя есть mode, который w, и который потом нигде не используется в коде класса.

Подсказка, где менять:

```
self.file=open(self.filename)
```

Описание:

Create a new file if it does not exist:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
```